# How to detect which of a set of elements is below center of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, positioning

Looking for ideas on how to detect which element of a set is currently at center of viewport.

From a set of block level elements stacked under each other in a document. How do I detect which of these is currently under imaginary fixed position crosshairs at the center of the viewport?

```
//
```

Starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/Xbhcv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the centre position:

```
var center_x = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/2);
var center_y = Math.floor(window.innerHeight/2);
```

Then iterate over all the elements you want to check and check if the `center_x` and `center_y` fall within them.

```
$(".detector").each(function(){
    x = $(this).offset().left;
    y = $(this).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    w = $(this).width();
    h = $(this).height();
    if(center_x > x && center_y > y && center_x < x+w && center_y < y+h){
        // the $(this) element intersects with the centre
        $(this).attr('id')
    }
}
```

and wrap this all in a `$(window).scroll` event.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XPQm/1/)

Comment: I'm going to award this answer Benjamin because it was the cleanest and in the end probably the most use to anyone viewing this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be cleaner, but this should basically do what you need:

```
// How to get the id of the element .detector div currently under the crosshairs?
      var crosshairPositionTop = $(".crosshairs").offset().top,
                crosshairPositionLeft = $(".crosshairs").offset().left,
                detectorPositionTop, detectorPositionLeft;
        $(".detector").each(function() {
            detectorPositionTop = $(this).offset().top;
            detectorPositionLeft = $(this).offset().left;
            if (detectorPositionTop < crosshairPositionTop && detectorPositionLeft < crosshairPositionLeft) {
                console.log($(this).attr("id"))
            }
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xbhcv/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that finds your crosshair position (the exact center of the green square), and loops through each of the `detector` divs to see which one contains it. It prints the containing div to console and highlights it in red on the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/Xbhcv/6/